# Allow inlining in shared libraries with fPIC

Tags: c++, linker, g++, dynamic-linking

So, I have simple cpp program

```
int f() {
    return 1;
}

int g() {
    return f();
}

int main() {
    return 1; 
}
```

I compile it with
`g++ a.cpp -O3` and with `objdump -Cd a.out` I see the following:

```
00000000000005f0 <f()>:
 5f0:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
 5f5:   c3                      retq
 5f6:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 5fd:   00 00 00

0000000000000600 <g()>:
 600:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
 605:   c3                      retq
 606:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 60d:   00 00 00
```

That is, both `f()` and `g()` are compiled to jut return 1. So far, so good.

Now, I want to provide both `f()` and `g()` as a public function in my new shared library.

I compile the same file with `g++ -shared a.cpp -O3 -fPIC` and get this:

```
00000000000005e0 <f()>:
 5e0:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
 5e5:   c3                      retq
 5e6:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 5ed:   00 00 00

00000000000005f0 <g()>:
 5f0:   e9 fb fe ff ff          jmpq   4f0 <f()@plt>
```

Now calling `g()` is not optimal -- it requires jump to plt table, etc

In this particular case I could compile without `-fPIC` and get the inlining because it is such a simple example, but my understanding is that in general I can't compile shared library without `-fPIC`.

So my question is, how do I allow internal inlining of code in the shared library?
I'm willing to accept that I can't replace the functions from outside (with the same functions in other shared libraries, for example with `LD_PRELOAD`) but I want to still be able to call it

Examples are with g++-9.3 on Ubuntu 18.04 (x86_64)

Comment: Specifically from the duplicate, use `-fno-semantic-interposition`  to allow inlining (and prevent the possibility of interposition).

Comment: @interjay indeed, that helps, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting clang optimizes this but GCC doesn't:
https://godbolt.org/z/8hrEjd

Maybe it's worth reporting to GCC?